# How to get the lasted test grade in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe

beginner here
I got a dataframe like this

[image]

My question is how I can get the latest overall score of each student_id?. I have attempted the question with groupby, but I did not get the desire results. Please help me, thank you.

Comment: You can group by student_id, and sort by date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `df` is your dataframe:

```
 df.drop_duplicates(subset='student_id', keep="last")
```

Comment: nice and simple. Thank you ^^

Comment: Shouldn't you use `first` since the `last` entry is the oldest?

Comment: @thanhpham if my answer is correct vote it as correct answer by ticking it under the down arrow.

Comment: this wont work if the dataframe isn't sorted by date

Answer (score 1):

I would group by student_id, then pick the latest entry by date.

```
for student, group in df.groupby('student_id'):
    last_grade = group.loc[group.date == group.date.max()]['overall score']
    print(student, last_grade)
```